# Bidirectional one-to-one association: Hibernate fetches entities twice

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have two entities,`Contract` and `Customer` between which there is defined a bidirectional one-to-one relationship:

**In Customer.hbm.xml:**

```
....   
<many-to-one name="contract" class="Contract" fetch="select">
    <column name="CONTRACTID" not-null="true" unique="true" />
</many-to-one>
```

**In Contract.hbm.xml:**

```
...
<one-to-one name="customer" class="Customer" property-ref="contract" />
```

When iterating over a collection `Customer` entities (fetched in some HQL query) and for each `customer` accessing a field of `contract`, Hibernate does two additional statements for each 'customer':

1. Lazy fetch of `contract` which is OK for me as I am going to optimize the lazy fetching with `batch-size` attribute later on.
2. Again fetching the `Customer` object with `SELECT ... FROM Customer WHERE CONTRACTID=?`

How to tell Hibernate to use the `customer` instance which is already present in the session?

**EDIT:**
If this is not possible because the `Customer` is fetched by `CONTRACTID` instead of `Customer`'s primary key in 2.), this scenario imposes another N+1 problem, right?

Comment: A bidirectional one-to-one suggests that you can only have a single contract for a customer is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to use the following workaround:

1) changing the `one-to-one` in `Contract` to an `<set...` (one-to-many) with `lazy="true"`, `access="field"` and `inverse="false"`. The property is named `customers` instead of `customer`

2) in the java class `Contract` I introduced the new `customers` property, but without new setter and getter (that's why we need the `access="field"`.

3) changed getter of the old single value property to return the first element of the `customers` set, if and only if it is not null and has size=1

4) changed the old setter to initialize a new HashSet and add the only `customer` to it.

This way the entity API did not change and I have the illusion that it is mapped as one-to-one ;-). Nevertheless, I would appreciate another solution